# $\vec{a} \cdot (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) = \vec{b} \cdot ( \vec{c} \times \vec{a})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I've seen my teacher of general physics write $\vec{a} \cdot (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}) = \vec{b} \cdot ( \vec{c} \times \vec{a})$ but I've search for a proof in google and there is nothing. I also tried to prove it myself but I couldn't. I need help

Comment: Write out components.

Comment: That follows from either geometric or determinant properties of the [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Geometric_interpretation).

Comment: Do you know that swapping any two rows of a matrix results in a determinant that differs from the original only by sign? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Immediate_consequences

Comment: Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/314275/334795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the many ways to define the scalar triple product is: Let $\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, $\vec{b}=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and $\vec{c}=(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ then we have
$$
\vec{a}\cdot (\vec{b}\times\vec{c})=\begin{vmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
c_1&c_2&c_3\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
So exchanging $f_1\leftrightarrow f_2$ and $f_2\leftrightarrow f_3$ we have this
$$
\begin{array}{rcr}
\vec{a}\cdot (\vec{b}\times\vec{c})&=&\begin{vmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
c_1&c_2&c_3\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=&-\begin{vmatrix}
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
c_1&c_2&c_3\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=&(-1)^2\begin{vmatrix}
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
c_1&c_2&c_3\\
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
\end{vmatrix}&=\vec{b}\cdot (\vec{c}\times\vec{a})
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The result follows from the identity
$a\cdot (b\times c) = \det(a|b|c)$, where the determinant is of the matrix whose columns (or rows, if you prefer) are $a$, $b$, and $c$ respectively.  Then, you need to know that swapping two columns of a matrix will multiply the determinant by $-1$.  This yields:

$$\begin{split}a\cdot (b\times c) &= \det(a|b|c) \\
                                  &= -\det(b|a|c) \\
                                  &= \det(b|c|a)\\
                                  &= b\cdot (c\times a)\end{split}.$$

As for why we have the relationship to determinants, this follows from expansion by minors for computing determinants, and the definition of cross product.  In some sense, making this formula hold is why the cross product is defined like it is.

Comment: Nice answer. I would just add that, in fact, this is often taken as the formal *definition* of the cross product. By the Riesz theorem, for fixed vectors $b,c$ the linear functional $f(x)=\det(x,b,c)$ is represented by a unique vector, denoted $b\times c$, under the inner product, so that $\det(a,b,c)=f(a)=a\cdot(b\times c)$.